# How do I resize an image after converting it from a BLOB?

Tags: c#, .net, resize, blob, generic-handler

I am trying to resize an image server side inside my generic handler right after it is converted back to an image from the BLOB in a database...This is my handler code:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Image" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

public class Image : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        Guid id = new Guid(context.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
        int column = 7;

        if (context.Request.QueryString["img"] == "tbn")
        {
            column = 6;
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(returnImage(id, column));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        }
    }

    public Byte[] returnImage(Guid id, int column)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlCn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=user;Password=password");

        string qry = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE Id=@id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, sqlCn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = id;
        sqlCn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        Byte[] ar = (Byte[])(dr[column]);
        dr.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        sqlCn.Close();
        return ar;
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

It should look wheter the image width is higher than its height and the opposite and according to that set a height or width and the other value (height/width) should be set proportionally so it won't get stretched.

What I found is this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25838/A-Simple-Image-Handler

But I don't really know how to use it...Any suggestions? Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little long-winded, but it works for me. Given a memory stream from the blob, plus target width and height dimensions, it will return a new stream with a resized copy of the image.

```
 public static Stream CreateThumbnail(Stream input, Int32 targetWidth, Int32 targetHeight)
    {
        output = new MemoryStream();
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(input))
            {
                ImageFormat format = bitmap.RawFormat;
                Boolean isJpeg = (format.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg));
                Boolean isPng = (format.Equals(ImageFormat.Png));
                Int32 width = bitmap.Width;
                Int32 height = bitmap.Height;
                getTargetSizes(out width, out height, bitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight);
                using (Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
                {
                    Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailBitmap);
                    G.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    G.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
                    thumbnailBitmap.SetResolution(72, 72);
                    if (isJpeg)
                    {
                        var codecParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        codecParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 80L);
                        ImageCodecInfo[] arrayICI;
                        ImageCodecInfo jpegICI = null;
                        arrayICI = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayICI.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (arrayICI[i].FormatDescription.Equals("JPEG"))
                            {
                                jpegICI = arrayICI[i];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        thumbnailBitmap.Save(output, jpegICI, codecParams);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        thumbnailBitmap.Save(output, ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
                }
            }
        return output;
    }

    private static void getTargetSizes(out Int32 targetWidth, out Int32 targetHeight, Bitmap BM, Int32 maxWidth = 150, Int32 maxHeight = 150)
    {
        Int32 startWidth = BM.Width;
        Int32 startHeight = BM.Height;
        targetWidth = startWidth;
        targetHeight = startHeight;
        Boolean resizeByWidth = false;
        Boolean resizeByHeight = false;
        if ((maxWidth > 0) && (maxHeight > 0))
        {
            if ((startWidth > maxWidth) || (startHeight > maxHeight))
            {
                if (startHeight <= startWidth)
                {
                    if(targetWidth > maxWidth) resizeByWidth = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(targetHeight > maxHeight) resizeByHeight = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (maxWidth > 0)
        {
            // Resize within width only
            if (startWidth > maxWidth)
            {
                if (targetWidth > maxWidth) resizeByWidth = true;
            }
        }
        else if (maxHeight > 0)
        {
            // Resize by height only
            if (startHeight > maxHeight)
            {
                if (targetHeight > maxHeight) resizeByHeight = true;
            }
        }
        if (resizeByWidth)
        {
            targetWidth = maxWidth;
            targetHeight = (Int32)(startHeight * ((Decimal)targetWidth / (Decimal)startWidth));
        }
        if (resizeByHeight)
        {
            targetHeight = maxHeight;
            targetWidth = (Int32)(startWidth * ((Decimal)targetHeight / (Decimal)startHeight));
        }
    }
}
```

And call it with something like:

```
MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(returnImage(id, column));
strm = CreateThumbnail(strm, 100, 100);
```

Comment: hmm...this code is HUGE :) and very confusing...how would I use this with my code?

Comment: The code could be made more compact, I'll grant you - I just grabbed it from an old project and I don't have time to rewrite it for you. You would use it by calling the first function, passing it your memory stream, and the width and height you wanted the image resized to, and putting the result back into your memory stream. I'll add an example.